# pass user information in every function of the controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Controller witch contains more than 150 functions. almost all of the functions inside the controller are returning views.
each view should change if the user is logged in. 
I almost handled this in the view side by using parent blades and etc. But in the controller side for almost every function i should check if the user is logged in and return some specific data about the user along with the view.
for example:

```
 $user=[];
 if(Auth::check())
 {
     $user=Auth::user;
     $reputation=$user['reputation'];
     $messages=$user->messages();
     $notifications=$user->notification();
 }
 return view('pages.profile')->with(['user'=>$user , 'messages'=>$messages , 'notifications'=>$notifications]);
```

I thought that this is possible using middlewares but i could not figure it out.
what are the alternatives here?
for more information i am using laravel 5.

Comment: I understand the problem you have, but do not understand how the code you pasted would explain the issue :) You're assigning some variables that are not used later. You also pass the user object which is enough to get all the needed data in the view. Could you please elaborate before I start answering not the question you had in mind? :)

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo in this code i just want to show i need to pass all these data for almost every view in my view set. and if i want to add a field to above data i should change the data in every function. what i am trying to do is to attach some data to almost every view that is returned by this controller.am i clear enouph?

Comment: Clear. But why not just pass only user to the template? You can always access messages in the template by calling $user->messages, etc. This way you'd always pass only user to the views.  Unless there is some more data you always want to pass to the views and not all of that is part of user model - if so, I'll try to find a solution for you.

Comment: yes that is obvious but most of the times there is some non relational joins that i am dealing with is involved. so if there is a way of doing this it will be very good.

Comment: also i got a thought in mind right now. to write a function that needs an argument witch is the view and the data is passed to that view. and inside that function i get the object and add the data i want. and when i want to change that data i just change the function. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be using your custom function instead of **view()**. Sth like:

```
//in your controller action
public function someAction() {
  return $this->view('pages.profile');
}

protected function view($template, $data = array()) {
  return view($template)->with($data)->with([data that needs to be passed to all views]);
}
```